# percentage increase in performance

Tags: characters

What is :

1. **by** how much
2. **to** how much

efficiency of algorithm is increased , if

Initially it was executing in 20 seconds,
after improvement (Final Time) it is executing only in 5 seconds.
My Try:

```
1. by how much : (Initial Time - Final Time)
                 --------------------------- * 100
                    Initial Time  
2. to how much : Initial Time
                 ------------- * 100
                  Final Time
```

tell me if i'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea, and perhaps I'm splitting hairs, but I think we could also swap the equations:

That is, the improvement increases performance **by** $$\frac{\text{initial time}}{\text{final time}}\times 100\% = 400\%.$$

The change leads **to** a $$ \frac{\text{initial time} - \text{final time}}{\text{initial time}}\times 100\% = 75\%$$ improvement in performance.

(perhaps you can clarify exactly how "by" and "to" are to be understood)

Comment: yes , I think you are correct.

Comment: Glad to help. I understand, completely. I've been known to "overthink" problems, myself.

Comment: @amWhy: Needs to TU to go with check. :-) =1